# HttpResponseRedirect in a method, cant use "return method(req)" as its giving error when method not returning

Tags: python, django

My code is like this :

```
def check(request):
    if(success):
        #nothing should do
    if(fail):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("http://google.com")

def index(request):
    return check(request)
    #some other taskshere after checking login
```

I read in other posts that in order to make `HttpResponseRedirect` work, we have to return it while calling , like :

```
return check(request)
```

when login fails, its ok , but when login is success the method check is not returning anything, so giving error that **index**  method didnt return an `HttpResponse` Object . Whats  the solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the auth decorators for this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

If you simply must, there are a variety of ways. You could do it as you describe:

```
def index(request):
    auth_situation = check(request)

    if auth_situation is None:               
       # some other tasks here, render a template,
       # redirect, do something, man!
    else:
       return auth_situation
```